# Using a VPN inside a VM over SOCKS

Tags: vpn, socks, checkpoint

At work my PC is ubuntu based, and we are migrating to a VPN that only comes with a client for windows based machines. It seems almost impossible to hack the client to work on Linux (or it will require some real tedious work, let's assume it is impossible). I was wondering, should I be able to fire up a Windows VM on my PC, run a SOCKS server and connect to the VPN over that? I mean let's say I need to access our gitlab server - how would I do that over the Windows VM on my ubuntu host?

Comment: Linux already has native clients for many commercial VPNs, and this may not be necessary. Check first.

Comment: Sadly impossible. I have to use such solution